# Tried to install Ubuntu alongside Win10. Ubuntu boots into grub needing to find kernel

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, system-installation, grub

I'm very new to Linux and I wanted to try Ubuntu.

I wanted to install it on my M.2 NVME which also has my windows installation on it. Only to find out that when I got to the section of selecting "install alongside windows" it only gave me the option to install it my SSD. I was planing on putting my base installation on my C drive and formatting that SSD for Ubuntu anyway, so I just allocated as much space as I could for it (336 GB) and continued the installation.

It gave me the okay to power down my system and remove the storage media. In the tutorial video I watched the instructor was greeted with a boot menu, but for me I was greeted with this GNU GRUB 2.04 command line. So do I not have a boot menu because it wasn't installed alongside Windows on my `C:` drive? Also, why does GRUB say I need to identify the kernel? Again I'm really new to this and any help would be really appreciated.

Also, my installation got stuck on the page that has the allocation slider for the drive. When I clicked continue it hanged there for about 20 mins, when I gave Ubuntu the shutdown command it suddenly kicked it out of its hangup. Not sure if this could be the culprit but I thought I'd mention it.

My installation was 20.04 LTS, I have also found my Ubuntu installation, it's on `(hd0, gpt3)`.

- My boot file has: `bootx64.efi`, `fbx64.efi`, `mmx64.efi`
- My Ubuntu file has: `grubx64.efi`, `shimx64.efi`, `mmx64.efi`, `bootx64.cav`, `grub.cfg`.

I'm using this guide, [How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/), but I don't know which of these files is my kernel.

Why doesn't the boot menu come up that lets me select which OS I want? When grub come up and I type "boot" it tells me I need to "identify the kernel first"

Comment: What is the question? You installed it so what's the problem?

Comment: Why doesn't the boot menu come up that lets me select which OS I want? When grub come up and I type "boot" it tells me I need to "identify the kernel first"

Comment: none of those files are your kernel

Comment: [Edit] your post and put the question there, **not** in the comments. That is not what the comment section is for.